# eslint env: browser + no-use-before-define

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm using eslint with the following notable settings

- `env: browser`
- `no-use-before-define: 2`

There is a line of code:

`var window = $(window);`

which is raising this error from eslint:

> 'window' was used before it was defined  no-use-before-define

Do eslint rules now how to cooperate? Seems like with `env: browser`, the `no-use-before-define` rule should not raise an error here, because `window` is assumed to be defined. [Here](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments) is the note on `env: browser`:

> An environment defines global variables that are predefined. The
> available environments are:
>
> browser - browser global variables.

EDIT:

[Here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/coding-standards/code-standard-javascript.html) are the rules I'm using (M2 recommended JS formatting).

Comment: From what you've posted it does seem this should work. Are you able to post additional code?

Comment: @aprouja1 I just added a link to the rules I'm using.

Comment: Why are you defining window when it's already defined?

Comment: Looks like it's being wrapped in jquery; if I change it to `var w = $(window);` the warning goes away. Not the greatest line of code (the original), but I think it should have nonetheless passed. Must be an edge case. Thanks for your help!